# Multiple LightDM's

Tags: lightdm

Relatively not long ago I had found out about different Display managers for Ubuntu and decided to try `gnome`. After that I wanted to go back to `lightdm`, and when I executed the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightDM` the normal screen pops up (*fig. 1*).

[image: Fig 1]

But after that there are two lightDM's in the menu (*fig. 2*). Why is that?

[image: fig 2]

Comment: AFAIK there is only `lightdm` - I suspect this is just a quirk in `dpkg-reconfigure` whereby it "corrects" the case for you (I can replicate the issue on my system - which has only sddm - by typing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure sdDM`)